# how can i make a conditional navigation in swiftui

Tags: swiftui, view, swiftui-navigationlink

im trying to make a conditional navigationlink  example if var = 0 still in the same view and nothing will change else it send me to the other view normally

```
HStack {
                Button   {
                    
                    if paymentType == nil {
                        self.showBanner = true
                        self.bannerData.type = .info
                    } else {
                        NavigationLink(destination:NewOfferStepThree() .navigationBarHidden(true)
                            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true))
                    }
                  
                } label: {
                    HStack {
                        
                        Text("Next")
                            .font(.system(size: 23.0))
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            .frame(width: 332.0, height: 28.0)
                            .opacity(100.0)
                        
                        Image("Icon ionic-ios-arrow-forward")
                            .offset(x: -30, y: 1)
                    } 
                } .frame(width: 332.0, height: 54.0)
                    .background(.black)
                    .cornerRadius(15)
                    .offset(x: 1, y: -80)
            }
```

but i have this error " Missing argument for parameter #1 in call" and didn't work for me

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve. Putting a View inside the action of the Button is doing nothing.

Comment: so what should i do  if i want to add a condition to navigationlink example i have a view with a  label if the label is empty    when i tap to the button next still in the same view and if the label is  full when i tap on the button next send me to the second view  taht's my goal and i don't know how

Comment: with `NavigationView`, there is a `NavigationLink(destination: Text("Destination"), isActive: $isActive, label: { Text("NavigationLink") })` that you could use, where you "trigger" the navigation with the `isActive:`. Look it up. Otherwise the traditional `if var == 0 {NavigationLink(...)}`